# How to read and write to Ask Ubuntu from command line?

Tags: discussion

Opening Ask Ubuntu in `w3m` yields pretty ugly results.

Does Ask Ubuntu have some sort of API, or custom CLI clients?

Maybe I should downgrade to mailing lists, or IRC, or usergroups? Know good ones?

Comment: Usually, a question about the site itself should be asked on [meta]. I'm not sure where this one belongs.

Comment: @muru on AU meta)

Comment: lynx isn't much better than w3m but at least it has better color coding

Comment: Interesting how I stopped receiving reputation for this question after it moved. Look at me caring about reputation. Ffff.

Answer (score 8):

Ask Ubuntu is part of the Stack Exchange network, and there's [a Stack Exchange API](https://api.stackexchange.com/). This can be used to publish to Stack Exchange sites, given [certain conditions](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/write).

Also look up [Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/). [This one](https://stackapps.com/questions/2802/stackoverflow-cli-a-nix-stackoverflow-command-line-client) might be interesting.

There's the official [Ubuntu Users mailing list](https://lists.ubuntu.com/mailman/listinfo/ubuntu-users), which is for
[technical support](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuUsersListFAQ), and [offical IRC channels](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/IRC/ChannelList) on Freenode.

Comment: Wow, that's nice. =)

Comment: Um, can't compile "That one" app. Thanks btw.

Comment: @PeretFinctor Note the user who commented on that post - Nathan Osman. He's a regular on [chat], so you might ping him there to see if he ever did do something with it.

Comment: I think I'll give up on that app. Pretty sure it's rotten by now, it's 3 years old. I managed to compile it, but it still gave an error. Btw why using API is so problematic? Can't spammers just pretend to be browsers anyway?

Answer (score 4):

Check this out:

- https://github.com/gleitz/howdoi